# Form validation alert or message not displaying, but the validation works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I realized Safari isn't compatible with the HTML5 required feature, so I tried to add in a Javascript validation script. The script is blocking the customer from moving forward, but the alert OR message is now showing up.

```
<div class="productdetailquantity"><?php echo"<form action='./itemsadded.php?view_product=$product_id' method='POST' id='formID'>"?>
    <select class="productsize" name='size' required><span id="sizeoptionMSG" style="margin-left:6px;color:darkred;"></span>
        <option value='' id="sizeoption">Select a Size</option>
        <option value='Small'>Small</option>
        <option value='Medium'>Medium</option>
        <option value='Large'>Large</option>
        <option value='XL'>XL</option>
     </select><br><br>
     <select class="productquantity" name='quantity'>
         <option value='1'>1</option>
         <option value='2'>2</option>
         <option value='3'>3</option>
         <option value='4'>4</option>
     </select>
</div><br><br>
<div class="productdetailaddbutton">


  <?php 
echo "<input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='$product_id' />
        <input type='submit' class='addtocart' name='add_to_cart' value='Add to cart' />";
    ?>


<script>
    var form = document.getElementById('formID'); // form has to have ID: 

<form id="formID">
form.noValidate = true;
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) { // listen for form submitting
        if (!event.target.checkValidity()) {
            event.preventDefault(); // dismiss the default functionality
            document.getElementById('sizeoptionMSG').innerHTML = document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '' ? 'Please, select a size' : ''; // Show message, NOT SHOWING UP
            document.getElementById('sizeoption').style.borderColor = document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '' ? 'darkred' : ''; // color field's border -- NOT SHOWING UP
            if (document.getElementById('sizeoption').value == '') document.getElementById('sizeoption').focus(); // Put cursor back to the field -- NOT WORKING
            alert('Please, select a size.'); // error message -- NOT WORKING
        }
    }, false);
```

Does anyone see anything that would be causing this to not display the alert or message? I've commented in the JS what parts are not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your first option of the first select box contains an ID attribute like **id="sizeoption"** but the select box itself doesn't have an ID. Is this purposeful or by mistake?

Comment: Purposeful. I want 1 as the default for that option.

Comment: I misread what you said. I took out the... id="sizeoption" ...from the option tags and put it in the select tags, but it still isn't displaying the message/alert..

Comment: Okay. Can you try removing from the span element immediately inside the select box?